# Share Internet to a Raspberry Pi Zero via USB connection

Tags: linux, networking, usb, raspberry-pi, internet

I have a `Raspberry Pi Zero` (without WIFI adapter) connected via `USB` to a `Raspberry 3B+` server with Internet Access (both `eth0` and `wlan0`). I am able to ssh into the `raspberry zero` and even have an `IP` with the serial connection, but, no Internet access.

Is there a way I can redirect or share the Internet from the Raspberry with access to the one connected via `USB`?

I followed this blog: https://blog.gbaman.info/?p=791
I also wrote some of the steps here: https://github.com/programandoconro/My-Linux-Locker-/blob/master/Raspberry/USB_serial.sh.

Thank you a lot,

EDITED:
These are the results after
`ifconfig -a`

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

usb0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 169.254.181.179  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 169.254.255.255
        inet6 *************  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ************* txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 85  bytes 10991 (10.7 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 68  bytes 11207 (10.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

...and `ip route ls`:

```
default dev usb0 scope link src 169.254.181.179 metric 202 
169.254.0.0/16 dev usb0 scope link src 169.254.181.179 metric 202
```

Comment: Can you provided the output of `ifconfig -a` on the pi 0 ?

Comment: And the output of `ip route ls` and `ip address ls`, when run on the Pi Zero, please.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani I edited the question with the output of the Zero. Thanks.

Comment: That looks like an USB ethernet adapter/gadget, not USB serial...

Comment: @dirkt It is a Raspberry Pi Zero (NO W) connected to a Raspberry Pi 3+B. No Ethernet adapter is connected. Maybe I am misunderstanding something? Thanks.

Comment: @dirkt I edited the question, I was confused with the serial connection, it is just USB connection? Thank you.

Comment: There are USB serial devices and USB ethernet devices. The RaspPi can simulate a USB ethernet device, and it will show up as a `usb0` network interface. If it would simulate a USB serial device, you'd see `/dev/ttyUSB0` or something similar, and would need `ppp` over this for networking. In both cases, you just connect with a simple USB cable.

Comment: And as for the question: As long as you have a link local (169.254.*.*) address on a network interface, it's not routable, and you won't get internet through forwarding. Give it a proper private IP address (e.g. 192.168.0.*/24).

Comment: @dirkt thank you for the clarification. I guess the 192.168.0.1/24 address should I set it on the zero right? But how do I do that? I am trying with the ``/etc/network/interfaces`` file on the zero.

Comment: You always need matching addresses on both sides (Zero and 3B+, ie.g. 192.168.0.1/24 on one, 192.168.0.2/24 on the other). There's a wide range of ways to do that, from using both `/etc/network/interfaces`, using systemd configuration, to running a DHCP server on the 3B+ if you want to connect other devices to it as well. If you are unsure about networking basics, please read up on that (there's plenty of material online).

Comment: I will try out both``interfaces`` and ``systemd`` approaches. If I manage to solve it (sounds totally possible), I will tag you on the answer so you can check it and improve it. Thank you a lot @dirkt,

Comment: I finally managed share internet to the ``zero``  using Fedora 32 with Gnome instead of the Raspberry Pi 3 server. I had to configure  the IPv4 method to ``share to other computers`` under the ``USB ethernet`` option in ``Network ``.  If I manage to do it in the server I will share the answer. Thank you @dirkt and @Eduardo for your kind help.